# Moving a quadword number to xmm registers

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, sse2

I am trying to move a number in a 64-bit register to an xmm register to do arithmetic. My thinking was:

`movq xmm1, r14`

In my program r14 is holding the counter and I need it to get moved into xmm1 so I can divide it with the sum of numbers i have stored in xmm0. And then display it.

When I execute the code, it stores 0 into xmm1.

Someone please help.

Comment: SSE2 does not support moves from general purpose registers to XMM registers, so the instruction should be illegal. What does it compile to?

Comment: @DocMax Everything compiles and assembles correctly. The only thing is that the number in r14 does not store into xmm1, so I just receive 0.000 in xmm1.

Comment: My mistake. I see now that MOVQ is documented in two places in the Intel instruction reference. I just put 0x123456789abcdef0 into r14, executed your line, and the bottom 64 bits of xmm1 are populated correctly. I'm stumped.

Comment: @DocMax What do you mean that its populated correctly? Could it be something else causing this problem then in my program?

Comment: I mean that XMM1 contains (as 8 16-bit values) `0:0:0:0:1234:5678:9abc:def0`. If you see that r14 is non-zero and xmm1 is 0 after that line, I'm not sure what else it _could_ be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created `test.asm` as:

```
section .code
global _start
_start:
    mov r14,0x123456789abcdef0
    movq xmm1, r14
    int 3
```

Compiled and linked with:

```
nasm.exe -f win64 -o test.obj test.asm
link.exe test.obj /entry:_start /subsystem:console
```

And ran it under the 64-bit WinDbg. When it hit the `int 3` WinDbg showed the registers as:

```
r14      123456789abcdef0
xmm1     0.000000e+000: 0.000000e+000: 5.690457e-028:-7.811515e-023
xmm1/0   9abcdef0
xmm1/1   12345678
xmm1/2   0
xmm1/3   0
xmm1l    1234:5678:9abc:def0
xmm1h    0:0:0:0
```

...and having typed all of that, is it possible that you are looking at `xmm1` as a floating point instead of integer values?

Comment: It could be that I am using xmm1 as a floating point number. If so should I use a different line of code or is it possible to convert?

Comment: Nevermind. I found the answer but thanks for the idea. I just used `cvtsi2sd xmm1, r14` and it works perfectly. Didn't even think about integer to float not working properly.

Comment: I wrote the same comment a few minutes after you did. :)
Glad you got it working.